# Lebesgue measure is continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

let $\lambda^n ((a,b])= \prod_{i=1}^n(b_i-a_i)$ be Lebesgue measure, I am yet to show that this is a measure however in the proof I need the following result:

Let $a,b \in \Bbb R^n$ then $f(r)=\lambda^n[(a,b+r])$ is a continuous function where $r\in [0,\infty)$

How can I show this?

Comment: Are you sure $a$ and $b$ are $n$-dimensional vectors? If so, $b+r$ is a rather peculiar quantity. If not, then by construction of Lebesgue measure $f(r)=b+r-a$.

Comment: @ClementC. I mean if $b=(b_1,\ldots , b_n)$ then $b+r=(b_1+r,\ldots , b_n+r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your notation (cf. comment), for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ fixed,
$$
f(r) = \prod_{i=1}^n (r+b_i-a_i)
$$
which is a polynomial function of $r$ (of degree $n$), and thus continuous.

Comment: I was typing that as a comment right now, asking you to answer so I could accept it. Thanks Clement.